# rewriting _.each function in Javascript not returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, underscore.js

Im trying to sharpen my skills in JS and rewriting the underscore.js utility functions. I'm stuck on the first one: each. This is what I have so far but when I run it in node, nothing is returned from iterator() being passed to each()? Please help

```
//_.each(list, iteratee, [context]); iteratee(element,index,list);

var arr = [1,2,3,4];

var each = function(list, iteratee) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        iteratee(list[i], i, list);
    }
}

var iterator = function(element, i, list){
    return element * 2;
}

each(arr,iterator);
```

What am I doing wrong and what rewriting these functions in the future, what is the best way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Not even the existing `each` function does return something? Didn't you actually want to write a `map` function?

Comment: Your code looks fine, but nothing you've written will show you any output. If you changed `iterator` to be `console.log(element * 2)`, then you should start seeing what is going on.

Comment: lol! how embarrassing. Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `each` function to return something you actually need to `return` something:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

var each = function(list, iteratee) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        // Write return value back to array
        list[i] = iteratee(list[i], i, list);
    }
    // return array
    return list;
}

var iterator = function(element, i, list){
    return element * 2;
}

each(arr,iterator);
```

This would return the array, what `underscore` and other popular libraries are doing is returning a wrapped set to enable chaining(`_.each().map().bla()`). All these libraries([underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore), [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash)) are open source, so i recommend to actually look at the source to understand how they operate.

Comment: `each` should never modify the array. What you have written here is more something like a `mutatingMap`

Comment: Well `each` should also not return an array, my goal was not to reimplement the `each` function but to transform the OPs code so it actually *does* something.

Comment: Thanks LJ. What am I invokking (or not invoking for that matter) for each to actually do something with the code ive written?

I have defined the iterator and passed it to each() as a callback which should return element * 2. Why is nothing being returned?

Comment: Your iterator **is** returning the doubled value, but you're not doing anything with it, this is where I in my modified snippet write it back into the array.